# In python turtle, when I want to show random motion of balls ,they are not bouncing off the edge of my screen

Tags: python, random, bounce, python-turtle

```
import turtle
import random
import time
```

we confirm ball is on left side of screen

```
def atLeftEdge(ball,screen_width):
    if ball.xcor()<screen_width/2: 
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

we confirm ball is on right side

```
def atRightEdge(ball,screen_width):
    if ball.xcor()>screen_width/2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

we confirm ball is on top edge

```
def atTopEdge(balls,screen_height):

    if ball.ycor()>screen_height/2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

we confirm ball is on bottom edge

```
def atBottomEdge(balls,screen_height):
    
    if ball.ycor()<-screen_height/2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now ball must bounce when it reaches edge of screen

```
def bounceBall(ball,new_direction):
    if new_direction=='left'or new_direction=='right':
        new_heading=180-ball.heading()
    elif new_direction=='up'or new_direction=='down':
        new_heading=360-ball.heading()
        
    return new_heading   
    


def createBalls(num_balls):
    balls=[]
    for x in range(0,num_balls):
        new_ball=turtle.Turtle()
        new_ball.shape('circle')
        new_ball.fillcolor('black')
        new_ball.speed(0)
        new_ball.penup()
        new_ball.setheading(random.randint(1,359)) #random angle between 1 to 359
        balls.append(new_ball)
    return balls
```

program starts here ,this is the main part of program where we take input from user and call all functions

```
 #------------------MAIN-------------------------------------------------      

print("The program stimulates bouncing balls in a turtle screen"\
      "for a specified number of seconds")
#TODO:create turtle graphics window object
#set up screen
screen_width=800
screen_height=600
turtle.setup(screen_width,screen_height)
#get reference to turtle window by calling Screen method
window=turtle.Screen()
window.title('Random balls on screen')
window.bgcolor('violet')
```

ask user to enter execution time and number of balls

```
num_sec=int(input("enter no of seconds to run"))
num_balls=int(input("enter no of balls in sim"))
```

create balls

```
balls=createBalls(num_balls)
```

set start time

```
start_time=time.time()
```

begin simulation

```
terminate=False

while not terminate:
    for x in range(0,len(balls)):
        balls[x].forward(40)

        if atLeftEdge(balls[x],screen_width):
            balls[x].setheading(bounceBall(balls[x],'right'))
        elif atRightEdge(balls[x],screen_width):
            balls[x].setheading(bounceBall(balls[x],'left'))
        elif atTopEdge(balls[x],screen_height):
            balls[x].setheading(bounceBall(balls[x],'down'))
        elif atBottomEdge(balls[x],screen_height):
            balls[x].setheading(bounceBall(balls[x],'up'))

        if time.time()-start_time>num_sec:
            terminate =True
#exit on close window
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: unrelated - you can rewrite your test to be :  `def atLeftEdge(ball,screen_width): return ball.xcor() < screen_width/2` - similar for the others. The comparision already returns a boolean value, no need to `if ...: return True else: return False` it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've change the `elif`s to `if`s as these are independent events.

```
if atLeftEdge(balls[x],screen_width):
    balls[x].setheading(bounceBall(balls[x],'right'))
if atRightEdge(balls[x],screen_width):
    balls[x].setheading(bounceBall(balls[x],'left'))
if atTopEdge(balls[x],screen_height):
    balls[x].setheading(bounceBall(balls[x],'down'))
if atBottomEdge(balls[x],screen_height):
    balls[x].setheading(bounceBall(balls[x],'up'))
```

also in `atLeftEdge` function you need to write your if this way :

```
if ball.xcor()<-screen_width/2:
```

also in `atTopEdge` and `atBottomEdge` I think you meant

```
def atTopEdge (ball , screen_height) :
```

and

```
def atBottomEdge(ball , screen_height):
```